# How add borderRadius for a photo inside children?

Tags: flutter, image, dart, widget, children

I tried to solve it the way I know it and every time there is  error..
I tried to solve it in `Radius` ...

Screenshot of the app

[Widget in the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhyST.jpg)

```
Widget getStaggeredGrid() {
  return StaggeredGrid.count(
    crossAxisCount: 15,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
    children: [
      StaggeredGridTile.count(
        
          crossAxisCellCount: 5, //
          mainAxisCellCount: 6, //
          child: Image.network(
            'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/cf/bc/6d/cfbc6d2dd13c9dc0977986847cb8c385.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,

            alignment: Alignment.center,
          )),
      StaggeredGridTile.count(
          crossAxisCellCount: 5,
          mainAxisCellCount: 4,
          child: Image.network(
            'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/fe/96/29/fe96299107f1b0b94fa434b6558d6568.jpg',
            //height: 60.0,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          )),
      StaggeredGridTile.count(
          crossAxisCellCount: 5,
          mainAxisCellCount: 9,
          child: Image.network(
            'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/71/84/7b/71847bcc4d8e4ab580c87dc6008cafb0.jpg',
            //height: 60.0,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          )),
      StaggeredGridTile.count(
          crossAxisCellCount: 5,
          mainAxisCellCount: 5,
          child: Image.network(
            'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/45/de/d4/45ded4dd846a4d994ae3afaf3345fb8e.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          )),
      StaggeredGridTile.count(
          crossAxisCellCount: 5,
          mainAxisCellCount: 3,
          child: Image.network(
            'https://i.pinimg.com/750x/a5/75/1e/a5751ed87fdbab76af299df228cb78ab.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          )),
    ],
  );
}
```

I tried to solve it in `Radius` ...

```
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
```

I think something is missing  I didn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I understood your question correctly,
but if what you want is to add border radius to the `Image.network` you added,

you can wrap the Image widget with `ClipRRect` or `ClipOval`.
Below is the captured image when `Image` is wrapped with `ClipRRect` and `ClipOval` and the code below image is how I did it.

Hope This helps.

[image: sample image for ClipRRect and ClipOval]

```
StaggeredGrid.count(
        crossAxisCount: 15,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        children: [
          StaggeredGridTile.count(
            crossAxisCellCount: 5, //
            mainAxisCellCount: 6, //
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              child: Image.network(
                'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/cf/bc/6d/cfbc6d2dd13c9dc0977986847cb8c385.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          StaggeredGridTile.count(
            crossAxisCellCount: 5,
            mainAxisCellCount: 4,
            child: ClipOval(
              child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                size: const Size.fromRadius(50),
                child: Image.network(
                  'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/fe/96/29/fe96299107f1b0b94fa434b6558d6568.jpg',
                  //height: 60.0,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          StaggeredGridTile.count(
            crossAxisCellCount: 5,
            mainAxisCellCount: 9,
            child: ClipOval(
              child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                  size: const Size.fromHeight(50),
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/71/84/7b/71847bcc4d8e4ab580c87dc6008cafb0.jpg',
                    //height: 60.0,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                  )),
            ),
          ),
          StaggeredGridTile.count(
            crossAxisCellCount: 5,
            mainAxisCellCount: 5,
            child: ClipOval(
              child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                  size: const Size.fromWidth(50),
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/45/de/d4/45ded4dd846a4d994ae3afaf3345fb8e.jpg',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                  )),
            ),
          ),
          StaggeredGridTile.count(
            crossAxisCellCount: 5,
            mainAxisCellCount: 3,
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                child: Image.network(
                  'https://i.pinimg.com/750x/a5/75/1e/a5751ed87fdbab76af299df228cb78ab.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                )),
          ),
        ],
      )
```